# Let $f\colon[0,8]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0) = 0, f(4) = 1$, and $f(8) = 1$, then $\exists c\in[0, 8]:f'(c)=1/12$.

Tags: calculus

This statement was an option for a multi-correct question. Using the following reasoning, I marked it as true, though the teacher says it was false. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

Given: $f\colon [0,8] → \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0) = 0, f(4) = 1,$ and $f(8) = 1$.
Applying Mean Value Theorem:
a) $\exists c_1\in (0,4):f'(c_1) = \frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4-0} = 1/4$
b) $\exists c_2\in (4,8): f'(c_2) = \frac{f(8)-f(4)}{8-4} = 0$

Since f is differentiable, it (i) must be continuous and (ii)(LHD $=$ RHD)
$\forall h\in(0,8), \lim_{x\to h^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to h^-}f'(x)$

therefore, in a sense, $f'(x)$ is a continuous function over $(0,8)$.
Since $f'(x)$ achieves value $0$ and $1/4$ (by a and b), it must also achieve $1/12$ somewhere in between.

Hence the given statement is true.

Is this reasoning correct? if not, what's the flaw?

Comment: Have you already searched for duplicate? I believe it's a dupe.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did search. Didn't find it. Could you please provide me a link(if any)? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Intermediate Value theorem? Do you know Darboux theorem? ( derivative of a function satisfy intermediate value property)

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, I am in high school (12th grade). At least my teacher won't accept any reasoning out of the syllabus

Comment: **Since $ f′(x)$ achieves value $0 $ and $1/4$ (by a and b), it must also achieve $1/12$ somewhere in between.** $\\$This is known as intermediate value property. Continuous function has intermediate value property. But here $f'$ need not be continuous. But $f'$ has the IVP( remember derivative has IVP). Your argument now works for $f'$.

Comment: I had used the same reasoning in the test. I just thought that I would give it some "rigor" (though I don't know much about proofs). Anyways thanks for letting me know of IVP. I will learn more about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g(x)={f(x+4)-f(x)\over 4}$$ Then
$g(0)={1\over 4}$ and $g(4)=0.$ Therefore by IVP there is $x_0,$ $0<x_0<4,$ such that $g(x_0)={1\over 12}$
i.e.
$${f(x_0+4)-f(x_0)\over 4}={1\over 12}$$
On the other hand by MVT there exists  $x_1,$ such that $x_0<x_1<x_0+4$ and $$f'(x_1)={1\over 12}$$

Comment: IVP is sometimes called the Darboux property. Any continuous function shares that property, and $g$ is continuous.  MVT is called the Lagrange theorem. You can look up in Wikipedia. I am certain that your teacher aimed at applying those elements in the solution.

Comment: I checked up IVP... I am embarrassed to say that I didn't know it... Its such a common sense thing after all... Thanks, now your solution makes sense... Its just that i had never read of IVP as "IVP" in any of my texts...

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a differentiable function need not be continuous. ($f$ is continuous but $f'$ need not be).  However, $f'$ has IVP (Intermediate Value Property). This is  called Darboux Theorem. Using this theorem your conclusion follows.

Ref.: [Darboux's thorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the "continuity of derivative" part. I'll keep this in mind from now on...